# Does Safari share cookies with subdomain if it has a different certificate?

Tags: ssl, safari, certificate, cross-domain

I can not manage to share a cookie between mydomain.org and shop.mydomain.org in Safari.

In Chrome it works and when I enter mydomain.org I can see the cookies of the subdomain, but in Safari it doesn't.

May it be related to the fact that mydomain.org has an AWS signed certificate and shop.mydomain.org has another one?

Here is what I see when in the developer tools:

Using Chrome at mydomain.org:
[image]

Using Chrome at shop.mydomain.org:
[image]

Using Safari at mydomain.org (here is the problem):
[image]

Using Safari at shop.mydomain.org:
[image]

Comment: Likely it is not related to the certificates. It would be actually useful to show how exactly you try to share the cookies.

Comment: Great idea! I just added some images that might help

Comment: There is no cookie set for `fridaylight.org`. There are only cookies set for `shop.fridaylight.org` (exact domain) and `.shop.fridaylight.org` (including subdomains). The only difference is that Chrome __shows__ the subdomain cookies when viewing the domain but not that it is actually __using__ it. So it is __only a difference in display__: cookies set __somewhere inside__ this domain vs. cookies set __at__ this domain.

Comment: Got it, I didn't realize it was just a difference in the display.
I am actually trying to make a request from fridaylight.org to shop.fridaylight.org (external service) and while in Chrome I do see that in every request there is a request cookie that is being updated, in Safari I only see a response cookie that is not being sent in the next request... That's why I thought it might be an issue specific to how Safari handles cross-domain security

Comment: I just realized that the library I am using is from 2015 and it is using JSONP for its requests, may it be that Safari doesn't send the cookies on the request because of that?

Comment: I cannot tell what exactly is going on with the current details. I doubt though that JSONP is the reason.